# javascript function to convert date from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyymmdd

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In asp.net when am selecting date using calender control it displays in textbox as

> mm/dd/yyyy (eg.5/19/2011)

format but in my sql database it is stored as varchar datatype in

> yyyymmdd(20110519)

format without any separators '/' or '-'.

Answer (score 2):

First parse the date (`DateTime.ParseExact(jsDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`), then use `parsedDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")` to format in the way you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex as

```
var myDate = "05/19/2011";
var regExp = /(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})/;
myDate.replace(regExp, "$3$1$2");
```

This is a javascript solution, can implement the same in `C#`

Comment: Fails where the input string doesn't include leading zeros where date or month is less than 10 per the OP, which also doesn't want '/' separator.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your input string doesn't include leading zeros, then if it's formatted exactly as posted:

```
function formatDateString(ds) {
  function addZ(n) {return n<10? '0'+ ~~n : n;}
  var bits = ds.split('/');
  return bits[2] + addZ(bits[0]) + addZ(bits[1]);
}
```